# CloudFormation - How to use Sub intrinsic function?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In the below JSON rule:

```
       {
         "Action": [
                "iam:CreatePolicyVersion",
                "iam:DeletePolicy",
                "iam:DeletePolicyVersion",
                "iam:SetDefaultPolicyVersion"
            ],
          "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::${Account:Id}:policy/policy1",
                "arn:aws:iam::${Account:Id}:policy/policy2"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny"
        }
```

---

How to use [Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) intrinsic function syntax in `Resource` section? to substitute variables...

**Edit:**

```
{
         "Action": [
                "iam:CreatePolicyVersion",
                "iam:DeletePolicy",
                "iam:DeletePolicyVersion",
                "iam:SetDefaultPolicyVersion"
            ],
          "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::${Account:Id}:policy/policy1"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny"
        }
```

How to refer single resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 {
         "Action": [
                "iam:CreatePolicyVersion",
                "iam:DeletePolicy",
                "iam:DeletePolicyVersion",
                "iam:SetDefaultPolicyVersion"
            ],
          "Resource": [
                {  "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/policy1"},
                {  "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/policy2"}
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny"
        }
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html

Comment: if it is just one resource? can i say... `"Resource": {  "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/policy1"},`

Comment: The policy is still expecting a list, you would need brackets, as its expecting an array of resources, in your case you would have an array with only one resource
`"Resource": [{ "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/policy1"}]`

Comment: I get error...`Syntax error at position (36,27)` for this... `"Resource": [{ "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:stack/some-stack*"}],` Position 27 is `"Fn`

Comment: That is hard to help with without seeing your full policy/template